Декодирование ASCII строки \x00\x00\x00\x02\ с помощью PHP
Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой что в кеше храним строку в виде \x00\x00\x00\x02\x14\x1A\x06\x00\x14\x0C\x11
и хотелось бы ее расшифровать
подскажите ее както можно расшифровать чтобы она была читаемой желательно с помощью PHP ?

Бред..... \x00 означает NULL ..... как ты предполагаешь, чтобы NULL был "читаем"? или \x06 - "Подтверждение"... как это должно быть "читаемо?"

\x00\x00\x00\x02 похоже на заголовок добавляемый сериализатором igbinary.

Это не текст, это бинарные данные, причём представленные во вполне дружественном к человеку формате ))

@u_mulder я думаю, вполне можно сделать ответом.

С помощью PHP декодируется 2 видами:
Функция декодирования бинарных данных (если строка уже в бинарном виде):
function binDecode($bin){
    $value = unpack("H*", $bin);
    return hex2bin($value[1]);
}
$bin = "\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46";
echo binDecode($bin);

В результате получаем:

0123456789ABCDEF

Если же данные именно в таком виде, \x30\x31, то сначала их надо перевести в бинарный вид, и функция будет выглядеть так:
function binDecode($bin){
    $result = '';
    $array = explode('\x', $bin);
    for($i=0; $i <= count($array); $i++){
        $result .= hex2bin($array[$i]);        
    }
    return $result;
}

Пример:
$bin = '\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46';
echo binDecode($bin);

Так же вернёт ответ:

0123456789ABCDEF

Ваши бинарные данные

\x00\x00\x00\x02\x14\x1A\x06\x00\x14\x0C\x11

не смогут прочитаться как текст, но вернут что то типа:

����


Вы очень смешно запутались в кавычках. Ваша исходная строка должна быть $bin = '\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46';. Теперь раскодируйте.

Если брать в такие кавычки, то функция вернёт:
\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46
Я прежде чем что то кому то отвечать, всегда проверяю на эмуляторе!
В PHP регулярные выражения как раз таки и вносятся в двойных кавычках: "\n", "\r" или "\xFF"

А при чем здесь какие-то регулярные выражения? Откуда вы их вообще взяли? :) Вам дали строку \x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46 - вот её и надо раскодировать.

Потому что именно так передаётся данные в функцию именно как БИНАРНЫЕ.
Чтобы отработала функция unpack внутри.
А передавая в одинарных кавычках ломает весь алгоритм действия, потому что передаётся просто строка. Если уж так коробят двойные кавычки, то функцию декодирования надо переделать:
function binDecode($bin){
$result = '';
$array = explode('\x', $bin);
for($i=0; $i <= count($array); $i++){
$result .= hex2bin($array[$i]);
}
return $result;
}

Вот и добавьте этот код в свой ответ. потому что сейчас функция декодирует не то, что спрошено. И тогда ваш ответ, хоть и бесполезный для автора вопроса, будет полезен хотя бы тем, кто придет сюда из поиска.

Дополнил ответ.

Теперь лучше. Хотя можно было сделать проще, hex2bin(str_replace("\\x","", $bin).

Тоже как вариант. Думаю есть и наиболее короткие решения. Но я предложил свой, хоть не очень короткий, но рабочий вариант. Хотя, отдать должное, PHP в этом и интересен, что даёт множество решений той или иной задачи.
